# iOS Localize/Internationalize Stopwatch or Timer Label

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

In my iOS app, I have a `UILabel` representing a stopwatch (ie the label reads 0:00 when it's reset, 0:01 a second after that, 1:01 a minute after that, etc.). I manually format the label so it reads as `HH:MM:SS`. But, I'm not sure if this format is extensible to all internationalizations; for example, in right-to-left layouts I'm assuming the correct layout would be `SS:MM:HH`.

I was able to find Apple's internationalization guidelines [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html) and a guide to formatting dates and times [here](https://evgenii.com/blog/localizing-numbers-date-time-and-names-in-ios-with-swift/), but neither of those guides say anything about the format of a stopwatch/timer (only the format of a clock time). Are there any specific guidelines (or better yet, APIs) for internationalizing the format of a stopwatch/timer in iOS?

Comment: `DateComponentsFormatter`.

Comment: Yep, looks like that's what I needed. Thanks!